# Can't Open JPG - Error interpreting JPEG image file

Tags: java, image-processing, https, upload

I did some sample uploads to OneDrive using graph api. I'm able to upload files (text files) successfully through OkHttp. But, when it comes to images I'm getting this message after opening image

```
Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xef 0xbf)
```

After uploading images to onedrive. `.svg` format images are uploading successfully but `.jpg, .png` format images are corrupting when uploading to one drive.

The following is my approach.

Converting the image to Byte array and then converting (writing) that Byte array to uploading file.

```
   String url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/root:/" + step.file_name + ":/content";

                    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url)
                            .put(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), step.file_data))
    //step.file_data contains the byte array.
                            .addHeader("Authorization", String.format("Bearer %s", step.getAccess_token()))
                            .build();
Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
```

This approach is working for text files and .svg format images but not for other format images. I went through many references/websites but unable to find a way. What could be the reason?!
Thank you :) in advance

Comment: As `svg` files are basically xml files (i.e.) text, I suspect your problem is in fact with _binary_ files. I don't know any `java`, so I'm just commenting, but _maybe_ is an [**endianness** problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I believe you're right. I had just come to the same conclusion but what can be wrong with byte/binary array!

Comment: It _might_ be that the byte array isn't written byte-by-byte but aggregated in some way (for speed?). I.e. you send 4 bytes ABCD from _your_ machine but they get written as BADC on the _remote_ server. As text files _usually_ composed of simple ASCII chars, they _might_ be handled byte-by-byte instead.

Comment: @MrShunz you are right mate. The problem is with the byte array itself. It took me whole day to figure out :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As SVG files are basically XML files (i.e. text files), I suspect your problem is in fact with *binary files*, most likely an [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) problem.

When the byte array gets assembled and streamed via the network, it isn't written byte-by-byte but aggregated in bigger chunks (probably for speed reasons).
For example, you want to send 4 bytes (`ABCD`) from your machine but they get written as `BADC` on the remote server.

As why with text files this does not happen... well usually text files composed of simple ASCII chars (unless they're encoded in UTF-8 or such...), so they are handled byte-by-byte instead.